# Passing context from Django views to Modal in template

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I have the below in my views.py.

```
def IPSEC_ANA(request):
    results = ''
    ipsec = IPSEC.objects.all()
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname='41.86.xx.xx', port=22, username='root',
                        password='xxxxxxx',
                        look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

    remote_conn.send('\n')
    remote_conn.send('en\n')
    remote_conn.send(str(password)+ '\n')
    remote_conn.send('sh run | i access-list ' + acl + '\n')
    remote_conn.send('\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    policy = remote_conn.recv(11111111)
    time.sleep(1)
    remote_conn.send('end\n')
    for line in policy.decode('utf-8').split('\r\n'):
        if 'access-list ' + acl + ' extended' in line:
            results = line
            print (results)
    context20 = {
        'ipsec': ipsec,
        'results': results,
    }
    template = loader.get_template('ipsecs.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context20, request))

def ipsecacl(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        acl = request.GET.get('acl')
        remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
        remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname='41.86.xx.xx', port=22, username='root',
                            password='xxxxxxxx',
                            look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

        remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

        remote_conn.send('\n')
        remote_conn.send('en\n')
        remote_conn.send(str(password)+ '\n')
        remote_conn.send('sh run | i access-list ' + acl + '\n')
        remote_conn.send('\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        policy = remote_conn.recv(11111111)
        time.sleep(1)
        remote_conn.send('end\n')
        for line in policy.decode('utf-8').split('\r\n'):
            if 'access-list ' + acl + ' extended' in line:
                results = line
                print (results)
    return render(request,{'results': results}, 'ipsecs.html')
```

This is my html:

```
{% extends "layouts/base-site.html" %}

{% block content %}
<main class="c-main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="fade-in">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Tunnel Info</div>
<div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-body">
       <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0">
         <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Tunnel Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Tunnel IP</th>
                <th class="text-center">Tunnel ACL</th>
               </tr>
            {% for items in ipsec %}
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>{{ items.tunnel_name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ items.tunnel_ip }}</td>
            <td class="button"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">{{ items.tunnel_acl }}</a></td>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    
                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>{{ results }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            
        </thead>
     </table>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </main>
```

The first function "def IPSEC_ANA(request)" is rendering all contents in my database in the table, from which it is working fine.

My issue is with the second function "def IPSEC_ANA(request)" when trying to render the context inside the modal.

I can't get it to work. The modal is blank.

Your help is greatly appreciated as usual.